# How to show confirmation dialog when deleting records in Odoo One2many tree list?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

In odoo, when you show a One2many field as a tree view, there is always a trash icon at the right side, that is used to delete the selected One2Many record. When you click that icon it deletes the record without confirmation. I was wondering if it is possible to show a confirmation dialog ("Are you sure you want to delete the record?") when clicking the trash icon in the One2Many fields tree list.
[image: Odoo One2Many tree list]

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `_onRemoveRecord` function to show a confirmation dialog when an attribute (`confirmOnDelete`) is set on the One2many field in the form view.

***Example:***

```
var core = require('web.core');
var FieldOne2Many = require('web.relational_fields').FieldOne2Many;
var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');

var _t = core._t;

FieldOne2Many.include({
    _onRemoveRecord: function (ev) {
        var _super =  this._super.bind(this);
        if (this.attrs.confirmOnDelete) {
             Dialog.confirm(this, _t("Are you sure you want to delete the record ?"), {
                 confirm_callback:  () => _super(ev),
             });
        } else {
            _super(ev);
        }
    },
});
```

A similar option is available for tree view and implemented in the controller, but the One2many widget only uses list renderer